# npm start error nodejs

Tags: node.js, debugging, npm, package

I give the command `npm start`. Terminal responds:

[image]

Comment: Yes, you need to have a proper nodeJS project before using npm start. Try running npm init first to create the package.json and add dependencies, start script etc.

Comment: I have this and other project projects. other projects are successfully launched and running. and this project does not work, I can send the source code  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1DOf1MTNYDofDRkdlU2CLIsHe2d1COpQW

Comment: The code you have sent should not generate this error as in the code npm start will run `SECRET=diplom nodemon index.js` but you image is not running that

Comment: in what there can be a reason, do not know?

Comment: Please [read this](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/) - images of code or exceptions are discouraged. We also need the code for the problem to be in the question itself - file lockers are not an acceptable substitute, because the links break too frequently.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are in correct directory when you run npm install, your current directory should have package.json file. for example based on the project you uploaded, you should be inside diplom folder and then run npm install.